# How to set iPhone wallpaper and ringtone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-4.0.1

How can I set a wallpaper and ringtone in the iOS SDK?

Comment: Way too vague, no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 3):

You cant programatically set a users wallpaper or ring tone...yet